# Appending data from one table to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I appended data from one table to another in SQL Server with this query:

```
INSERT INTO DESITINATION_TABLE (c1, c2, c3) 
    SELECT c1, c2, c3 
    FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

Then I have the data in the destination table looks like the following screenshot. Any idea how I can fix that? The data left-aligned is the newly added data, the data center-aligned is the old data.

[image: sql issue after appending data]

Thanks.

Comment: Data is not not aligned in the database. Perhaps you are storing numbers as varchars and they have left side padding? Or the existing data came from a fixed width location and has spaces on the right side?

Comment: Please, show the creation script of both tables.

Comment: thanks for all your comments Sean Lange is right, there are spaces padded to the left of the data in the original table's data. When I put a ltrim on all data when i do a select statement. It makes sense to me now.

Comment: @triston My pleasure! Such behavior could occurs when datatype of  columns is `nchar(n)`